# how do I classify or regroup dataset based on time variation in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, datetime

I need to assign number to values between different time hourly. How can I then add a new column to this where I can specify each cell to be grouped hourly. for instance, all the transactions within 00:00:00 to 00:59:59 to be filled with 1, transactions within 01:00:00 to 01:59:59 to be filled with 2, and so on till 23:00:00 to 23:59:59 to be filled with 24

```
Time_duration = df['period']

print (Time_duration)
```

````
0        23:59:56
1        23:59:56
2        23:59:55
3        23:59:53
4        23:59:52
           ...
74187    00:00:18
74188    00:00:09
74189    00:00:08
74190    00:00:03
74191    00:00:02 ```


# this is the result I desire.... How can I then add a new column to this where I can specify each cell to be grouped hourly. for instance, all the transactions within 00:00:00 to 00:59:59 to be filled with 1, transactions within 01:00:00 to 01:59:59 to be filled with 2, and so on till 23:00:00 to 23:59:59 to be filled with 24.

0        23:59:56        24
1        23:59:56        24
2        23:59:55        24
3        23:59:53        24
4        23:59:52        24
           ...
74187    00:00:18         1
74188    00:00:09         1
74189    00:00:08         1
74190    00:00:03         1
74191    00:00:02         1
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.sort_values(by=["period"])
timeStamp_list = (pd.to_datetime(list(df['period'])))
df['Hour'] =timeStamp_list.hour
```

try this code, this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regular expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) and [str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

```
import pandas as pd
pattern= r'^(\d{1,2}):' #capture the digits of the hour
df['hour']=df['period'].str.extract(pattern).astype('int') + 1 # cast it as int so that you can add 1
```